# (is) kernel busy in ipython notebook

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook

I'm using an EC2 spot instance (my windows to ubuntu instance) to run a function that was well beyond my laptop's capabilities. The kernel busy dot has been filled for hours. Previously, I would just listen to my laptop as it was obvious when something was running as opposed to ipnb getting stuck. Is there any way I can tell now?

If I try something like 1+1 in the box below my function it will also turn into an asterisk, but I can open a new notebook and have zero issues running simple commands in the new notebook.

Answer (score 1):

this is because all though each notebook has multiple cells but only one kernel, so the commands in the other cells are queued until the first cell finishes its task. When you open a new notebook that notebook is provided with its own kernel so it can do other simple commands quickly without attempting whatever it is that's taking so much cpu power